# Объединение таблиц в SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть условие запроса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получился такой запрос:

```sql
SELECT c.Country AS CustomerCountry, COUNT(e1.Country) AS ORDERS_TO_USA
FROM Customers c INNER JOIN Orders o
ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Employees e1
ON o.EmployeeID = e1.EmployeeID
WHERE (e1.Country = 'USA')
GROUP BY c.Country
ORDER BY c.Country
```

Но он выводит только кол-во заказов, обслуженных в США. Как теперь можно сделать и второй пункт про Великобританию? Пытался делать еще один join, но потом понял, что это бред. Может через union как-то или подзапросы?

**update:**

```sql
SELECT c.Country AS CustomerCountry,
CASE
WHEN e1.Country = 'USA' THEN COUNT(e1.Country) 
END AS ORDERS_TO_USA,
CASE
WHEN e1.Country = 'UK' THEN COUNT(e1.Country) 
END AS ORDERS_TO_USA
FROM Customers c INNER JOIN Orders o
ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Employees e1
ON o.EmployeeID = e1.EmployeeID
WHERE e1.Country IN ('USA', 'UK')
GROUP BY c.Country
ORDER BY c.Country
```

Ошибка:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column 'Employees.Country' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**update1:**

```sql
SELECT c.Country AS CustomerCountry,
CASE
WHEN MAX(e1.Country) = 'USA' THEN COUNT(e1.Country) 
END AS ORDERS_TO_USA,
CASE
WHEN MAX(e1.Country) = 'UK' THEN COUNT(e1.Country) 
END AS ORDERS_TO_UK
FROM Customers c INNER JOIN Orders o
ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Employees e1
ON o.EmployeeID = e1.EmployeeID
WHERE e1.Country IN ('USA', 'UK')
GROUP BY c.Country
ORDER BY c.Country
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с `CASE`:

```sql
WITH OrderWithCountryFlags AS
(
    SELECT o.CustomerID,
    CASE WHEN e1.Country = 'USA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as IsUSA,
    CASE WHEN e1.Country = 'UK'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as IsUK
    FROM Orders o
    INNER JOIN Employees e1 ON o.EmployeeID = e1.EmployeeID
)
SELECT 
    c.Country AS CustomerCountry, 
    SUM(IsUSA) AS ORDERS_TO_USA,
    SUM(IsUK) AS ORDERS_TO_UK
FROM Customers c INNER JOIN OrderWithCountryFlags o 
ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
GROUP BY c.Country
ORDER BY c.Country
```

Вариант с `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT CustomerCountry,
[USA] as ORDERS_TO_USA,
[UK] as ORDERS_TO_UK
FROM 
(
    SELECT c.Country AS CustomerCountry, o.OrderID, e1.Country FROM Customers c 
    INNER JOIN Orders o
        ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN Employees e1
        ON o.EmployeeID = e1.EmployeeID
) as SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(OrderID)
    FOR Country IN ([USA], [UK])
) as pvt
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Первый вариант прошел в MSQL, но в Oracle нет. Возможно как-то для Oracle изменить этот вариант?

Comment: @compl возможно в оракле нет CTE. Перепишите это как `SELECT FROM ..... (SELECT FROM ) ...` -  просто подставьте объявление `OrderWithCountryFlags` в то место, где они используются.

Comment: Я просто ";" убрал и вроде работает :)

Answer (score 3):

Такой вариант подойдет?

```sql
SELECT c.Country AS CustomerCountry, COUNT(IF(e1.Country='USA', 1, 0)) AS ORDERS_TO_USA, COUNT(IF(e1.Country='Great Britain', 1, 0)) AS ORDERS_TO_UK
FROM Customers c INNER JOIN Orders o
ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Employees e1
ON o.EmployeeID = e1.EmployeeID
WHERE (e1.Country IN ('USA', 'Great Britain'))
GROUP BY c.Country
ORDER BY c.Country
```

Я не уверен, сработает ли `IF()` в `t-sql`. Если нет, то можно будет воспользоваться `CASE` методом.

---

### Обновление

После обсуждения я не вижу других вариантов, кроме создания `PIVOT` таблицы. Однако сделать это без fiddle с данными крайне сложно.

Вот код, который можно взять за основу

```sql
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT c.Country as CustomerCountry, e1.Country as EmployeeCountry, o.id as orderID 
FROM Customers c 
JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
JOIN Employees e1 ON o.EmployeeID = e1.EmployeeID
WHERE e1.Country IN ('USA', 'UK')
) PIVOT (COUNT(orderID) FOR EmployeeCountry IN ('USA', 'UK')) as ordersPerCountry
```

Однако проверить его (еще раз) без fiddle у меня не возможности.

Вот неплохая статья в общих чертахз объясняющая создание таких таблиц.
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/spike/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample)
Разница в том, что в статье они использую таблицу как источник данных. В вашем же пример это будер результат `select` с `joins`.

Не знаю, чем еще помочь... :(

Comment: Спасибо, но с `IF()` вроде не хочет все-таки. Попробовал с `CASE`, но тоже не получается, хотя должно. Обновил вопрос с `CASE`.

Comment: Добавьте `e1.Country ` в `GROUP BY`

Comment: Добавил, но он теперь дублирует строки :)
(скрин добавил в вопрос)

Comment: А, ну да :) Тогда так... Убрать `e1.Country` из `GROUP BY` и заменить `WHEN e1.Country` на `WHEN MAX(e1.Country)`. Вобщем надо вокруг `e1.Country` поставить групповую функцию

Comment: Сделал. Но теперь суммирует все в один столбик с USA. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: :( ну да.... потому что MAX('US') больше, чем MAX('UK')... все он правильно делает... это я неправильно говорю... ща, подумаем... fiddle бы какой-нить...

Comment: Эх, ладно, спасибо. Буду разбираться.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе, этот запрос можно выполнить и без `CTE` ([полный пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b0ee/1)):

```
select 
  c.Country, 
  sum(case when e.Country = 'USA' then 1 end) orders_to_usa, 
  sum(case when e.Country = 'UK' then 1 end) orders_to_uk
from Customers c
join Orders o on o.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
join Employees e on e.EmployeeId = o.EmployeeId
group by c.Country
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
WHERE e1.Country IN ('USA', 'Great Britain')
...
```

Comment: Объясните, как ваша правка сформирует столбец `ORDERS_TO_UK`?

Comment: А, действительно, никак. Невнимательно смотрел на картинку, ориентировался больше на текст вопроса. :(

Answer (score -1):

Как делал я у себя

```
    $query_firms = mysql_query("select ls.id, ls.title, ls.id_parameter, ls.drag, ls.url, COUNT(`l`.`id`) AS `rcnt`, (`st`.`id`) AS `param`
                                        from leads_sort ls
                                          left join status st on ls.id_parameter = st.leadssort  
                                          left join lids l on st.id = l.status 
                                        where 
                                            ls.id_cabinet = $id_cabinet
                                        group by 
                                            ls.id
                                        order by 
                                            ls.drag");

    while($rew  = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_firms)) {

echo "".$rew['title']." (".$rew['rcnt'].")";

    }
```

Думаю разберешься как свои данные подставить.

Comment: При чем тут какой-то статус, кабинет и другая мура в запросе? И причем тут php?